# django model does not return primary key, why primary key is none

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

My code:

```
broadcast_obj = TblBroadcast.objects.using('broadcast_db').create(
                                name=request.POST.get('name'),
                                summary=request.POST.get('summary', ''),
                                cover=request.POST.get('cover'),
                                status=int(request.POST.get('status')),
                                quality=int(request.POST.get('quality'))
                                )
print "========="
print broadcast_obj.name
print broadcast_obj.summary
print broadcast_obj.cover
print broadcast_obj.status
print broadcast_obj.pk
print broadcast_obj.quality
print "========="
```

output:

```
=========
t
t
t
0
None
6
=========
```

why primary key is none? When I check the databases,the django have been create the item.The `broadcast_id` is `pk` and it is `auto_increment`.
[image]

Comment: did you define a primary key field in your model? update your question with the TblBroadcast model definition.

Comment: I had the same issue on v4.1 with my_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True), declared in the model. This id was always None when object was just created and got set when exiting scope. Changed the field type to AutoField (instead of Integer) and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Is your model have primary key?

```
class TblBroadcast(models.Model)
    broadcast_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Refer below 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields